# How should I round a float in this case?

Tags: c#, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I'm having issues in my code due to the multiple representations that a same float number can have.
For instance, these number are considered to be the same:

- 0.0299999400
- 0.0300000000

I don't care much for a big precision, I need to calculate **CRC** of those numbers and they should be the same, so my approach was to use this code:

```
private static float Rounding(float v, float p)
{
    return Mathf.Round (v * p) / p; 
}
```

Where *p* is my precision.

That seems to be working well, but in that case, if I used *p = 1e7*, the first number multiplication would result in *299999.4* and rounded to *299999*, becoming *0.0299999*, while *0.03* would remain *0.03*. That's my problem.

Am I doing the right thing? Maybe the answer is that I can't use a *p* this big, but I don't know how floats work, so I don't know the size of *p* to work in all situations.

However, I know that my float values resides in a range that is not as big as the float range (±1.5e−45 to ±3.4e38). What I mean is, if I know that my floats range is [-100; +100], I can assume that it will have enough decimal digits for *p* to be *3*. Is that right?

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Knowing the range tells you nothing about the precision.  Single precision floating point carries about 7 decimal places of precision.

Comment: @user92546 So, knowing the range wouldn't allow me to know how many digits after the decimal point I may have?

Comment: You know the range extends well past 10^30.  That fails to inform you that you have no control over anything to the right of the decimal point for numbers larger than 10^8.  Some double precision formats offer the same range, but greater precision than singles.  Others offer greater range with the same precision.  You can't teach 32 bits to do the work of 256.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should convert the numbers to [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) and then [round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131274.aspx) to the required precision. `decimals` are as accurate as they are precise, so you can then e.g. convert them to string and hash without having any such problems.

Comment: o.O Decimals just use decimal instead of binary arithmetic but they're not infinitely accurate. Things like 1/3 cannot be accurately represented in `decimal` either.

Comment: @Joey: True, that was bad wording on my part; changed to "as accurate as they are precise". Thank you for the catch.

Comment: @Jon Thank you. I don't think you mean *return (float) Math.Round(new Decimal(v), digits);*, right? I didn't say an important thing: besides CRC, I'm pursuing a deterministic simulation, so I got to receive a float and return a rounded float. I don't understand how decimal would make this work in that case that I have exatly 7 digits of precision :(

Comment: @Roberto: Returning a `float` is not what I had in mind, but rather working with a `decimal` from some point onwards. Although it sounds like converting to decimal, rounding and then back to float would result in a bitwise identical `float` for all values rounded to the same number.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm getting you right, but if you need those two numbers to be considered as equal, you could use:

```
Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal((float)0.0299999400),2); //result is 0.03
Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal((float)0.0300000000),2); //result is 0.03
```

And there you have it. If you want to round your numbers to a precision of 1e7 then off course those two numbers will be different.

Comment: Thank you. The question is about finding a precision that will work always.

Comment: @Roberto That is what I think you should explain better, what *always* and what *works* exactly means to you? Could you give more examples of inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: Always means for any float inside a range, in my case is [-100; +100]. Works means that for any float representation of a number, after rounding I'll get bitwise identical floats. So, for some *p* that I use, my code may or may not work, I want to know the value of *p* that could be used to *work always*.