# Bitwise representation of division of floats - how division of floats works

Tags: c#, floating-point, floating-accuracy

A number can have multiple representations if we use a float, so the results of a division of floats may produce bitwise different floats. But what if the denominator is a power of 2?

AFAIK, dividing by a power of 2 would only shift the exponent, leaving the same mantissa, always producing bitwise identical floats. Is that right?

```
float a = xxx;
float result = n/1024f; // always the same result?
```

--- UPDATE ----------------------

Sorry for my lack of knowledge in the IEEE black magic for floating points :) , but I'm talking about those numbers Guvante mentioned: no representation for certain decimal numbers, 'inaccurate' floats. For the rest of this post I'll use 'accurate' and 'inaccurate' considering Guvante's definition of these words.

To simplify, let's say the numerator is always an 'accurate' number. Also, let's divide not by any power of 2, but always for 1024. Additionally, I'm doing the operation the same way every time (same method), so I'm talking about getting the same results in different executions (for the same inputs, sure).

I'm asking all this because I see different numbers coming from the same inputs, so I thought: well if I only use 'accurate' floats as numerators and divide by 1024 I will only shift the exponent, still having an 'accurate' float.

You asked for an example. The real problem is this: I have a simulator producing sometimes 0.02999994 and sometimes 0.03000000 for the same inputs. I thought I could multiply these numbers by 1024, round to get an 'integer' ('accurate' float) that would be the same for those two numbers, and then divide by 1024 to get an 'accurate' rounded float.

I was told ([in my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943860/how-should-i-round-a-float-in-this-case)) that I could convert to decimal, round and cast to float, but I want to know if this way works.

Comment: Interesting question! I'd like to know as well.

Comment: No, after your value gets converted from base 10 to base 2 there is only one possible representation.  And dividing by a power of 2 only adjusts the exponent.  Converting the result back to base 10 to display it is going to produce different noise digits if you display too many of them.  Float has only 6.5 significant digits so be sure to trim off the garbage.

Comment: "The real problem is this..." - so, this should be your question, maybe with some specifics about the inputs and the operations performed.  Ideally with a reasonably short bit of example code that produces different outputs for the same input.

Answer (score 5):

> A number can have multiple representations if we use a float

The question appears to be predicated on an incorrect premise; the only number that has multiple representations as a float is zero, which can be represented as either "positive zero" or "negative zero". Other than zero a given number only has one representation as a float, assuming that you are talking about the "double" or "float" types.

Or perhaps I misunderstand. Is the issue that you are referring to *the fact that the compiler is permitted to do floating point operations in higher precision than the 32 or 64 bits available for storage*?  That can cause divisions and multiplications to produce different results in some cases.

Comment: I believe he is referring to how `0.1` * `10.0` can sometimes have a different representation than `1.0`.

Comment: Only zero and NaN have multiple representations. Denormals are in essence a fixed point subset of floats used to enable 'gradual underflow.' They are all unique.

Comment: @JeffreySax: You are of course correct; I was forgetting that they were *fixed point*. I'll fix that up.

Answer (score 4):

Since people often don't fully grasp floating point numbers I will go over some of your points real quick. Each particular combination of bits in a floating point number represent a unique number. However because that number has a base 2 fractional component, there is no representation for certain decimal numbers. For instance `1.1`. In those cases you take the closest number. [IEEE 754-2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) specifies round to nearest, ties to even in these cases.

The real difficulty is when you combine two of these 'inaccurate' numbers. This can introduce problems as each intermediate step will involve rounding. If you calculate the same value using two different methods, you could come up with subtly different values. Typically this is handled with an epsilon when you want equality.

Now onto your real question, can you divide by a power of two and avoid introducing any additional 'inaccuracies'? Normally you can, however as with all floating point numbers, denormals and other odd cases have their own logic, and obviously if your mantissa overflows you will have difficulty. And again note, that no mathematical errors are introduced during any of this, it is simply math being done with limited percision, which involves intermittent rounding of results.

EDIT: In response to new question

What you are saying could work, but is pretty much equivalent to rounding. Additionally if you are just looking for equality, you should use an episilon as I mentioned earlier `(a - b) < e` for some small value `e` (`0.0001` would work in your example). If you are looking to print out a pretty number, and the framework you are using isn't doing it to your liking, some rounding would be the most direct way of describing your solution, which is always a plus.